# Stipe Elements: This Element will be mounted to a DOM element that contains child nodes

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I have a popup that allows us to take payment via Stripe Elements. Everything loads fine the first time I want to make a payment. But if I hit the pay button and get a Stripe error response, i.e.

```
We are experiencing issues connecting to our payments provider. You have not been charged. Please check your internet connection and try again.
```

If I then close the popup and try to bring the form up again I get this warning in my console:

```
This Element will be mounted to a DOM element that contains child nodes.
```

I am not sure how to remove that warning. I haven't been able to find anything out there that solves my problem. I have tried unmounting the card when I close the modal but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
this.stripeCard.unmount();
```

Here is my code for component.ts:

```
   setTimeout(() => {
        const elements = ctrl.paymentService.stripe.elements({
            locale: "auto"
        });

        /**Card Element*/
        ctrl.stripeCard = elements.create("card", {
            // setting styles here
        })

        ctrl.stripeCard.mount('#credit-card-form');

        let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = "";

        // show any error messagaes associated with the card element
        ctrl.stripeCard.addEventListener('change', function (event: any) {
            let displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            if (event.error) {
                ctrl.cardValid = false;
                ctrl.cd.detectChanges();
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                ctrl.cardValid = true;
                ctrl.cd.detectChanges();
                displayError.textContent = "";
            }
        });

        // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
        let form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        (<any>form).addEventListener('submit', function (event: any) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ctrl.paymentService.stripe.createToken(ctrl.stripeCard).then(function (result: any) {
                if (result.error) {
                    ctrl.submittingCharge = false;
                    ctrl.chargeCompleted = false;
                    ctrl.cd.detectChanges();
                    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                    let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);

                    console.log(ctrl.customer);
                    ctrl.submittingCharge = false;
                    ctrl.chargeCompleted = true;
                    ctrl.cd.detectChanges();
                }
            });
        });
    }, 0);
```

Here is my html code:

```
<form id="payment-form" method="post" action="#" class="form">
       // other name, email, address input elements here
        <fieldset>
           <div class="row">
              <div id="credit-card-form"></div>
           </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button *ngIf="!submittingCharge" [disabled]="!purchaseValidation.valid || !cardValid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-2 py-3 cursor-pointer">Charge
                                {{payment | currency: 'USD' : 'symbol'}}</button>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? One of my users is seeing the same issue in an ASP.Net MVC application.

Comment: This is part of the answer I got from Stripe:

"This error usually indicates that something is wrong on the customer's connection and prevents them from reaching Stripe's servers.

Often, there are some errors in your Javascript console that explains what could be causing this. In other cases, it's due to a bad browser extension blocking outgoing requests to our servers.

You'd need to try in a different browser or in private browsing mode where extensions are disabled."